# MySQL Query is only loading certain items

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using this query to join media items with slide items, it's working and linking the appropriate media items with the mediaid in the slide table, but the issue I'm facing now is if there is no mediaid in the slide table nothing will appear at all.

```
"SELECT slide.*, media.*, slide.id AS slideid
FROM slide JOIN media ON slide.mediaid = media.id
WHERE media.id = slide.mediaid ORDER BY sort ASC"
```

How can I get this query to do what it does now, but to list all slide results even if mediaid is null?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and remove the `WHERE` clause:

```
"SELECT 
       slide.*, 
       media.*, 
       slide.id AS slideid
FROM slide 
LEFT JOIN media ON slide.mediaid = media.id
ORDER BY sort ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`

```
"SELECT slide.*, media.*, slide.id AS slideid
FROM slide LEFT JOIN media ON slide.mediaid = media.id
WHERE media.id = slide.mediaid ORDER BY sort ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your `WHERE CLAUSE`

```
"SELECT slide.*, media.*, slide.id AS slideid
FROM slide JOIN media ON slide.mediaid = media.id ORDER BY sort ASC"
```